# How properly to handle error/exception on frontend React and backend .NET/C#

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net

My frontend React interacts with backend on .NET/C#.

User clicks on button and passes int number to backend. It's OK if the number is positive, but if it is <0, it causes exception.

I can handle response from backend by response.ok or response.status, but I don't have an idea how to deal with error on backend side.

React code fragment:

```
const requestCalculation = {
    calculate: (number) => {
      const url = `/calculator/calculate?input=${number}`
      return fetch(url).then(response => {
      if (response.ok) { return response.text() }
      throw new Error('Something went wrong');
    }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
  },
};

return <button onClick={
              try{var promise = requestCalculation.calculate(-1); }
              catch(error){
                throw new Error(error.message);
              }> Click <button />
```

.Net/C# code fragment (only corresponding method):

```
public int calculate(int input) {
if(input<0) throw new Exception("Negative numbers are not allowed");
            int[] res = new int[input];
            /*
      some calculation
            */
    return res[input];
}
```

Comment: You'd need to define what you mean by "properly". All depends on what you want your user experience to be.

Comment: Thank you for you response @PaulDempsey I would like to inform a user about the reason why the code works not as expected. Can I get information on frontend about the reason "incorrect input - negative number" or it's better to validate input on frontend side?

Comment: That's a matter of opinion where it's best to validate/normalize input. There are tradeoffs, and depends in part where you want to put complexity. My preference is for APIs to require valid input and provide minimal details about errors. The UI layer knows the most about users and behavior and user experience, and has the most control over user input, so has the most information available to help users, so I think it's the burden of the ui code to form valid input before calling an API. But that's an opinion, and there are circumstances where it's "better" to do most of the work server-side.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET you could use [AddProblemDetails factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0), this is suggestion from Microsoft to describe how API should handle exceptions. To add your exception handler you should create factory of problem details and that overwrite it in **Program.cs**.

[This is an example](http://stevenmaglio.blogspot.com/2019/12/create-custom-problemdetailsfactory.html) of how to use it.

On React side you also could do something like

```
export abstract class YourExceptionHandler {
public static HandleException(error: Error) {
   //switch case stuff
}
```